# Archive files not modified for more than 6 months

Tags: files, find, date

I have a python method to archive files not modified in 6 months to another drive by iterating through the directories. But what is the fastest way to find all non-modified files from the whole partition?

Found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33850/list-of-recently-modified-files) below answer to find modified files and I suppose it is in the current path. But what If the root path is given and want to list all unmodified files.

I would like to modify the question a bit based on an observation I found in the answer I have posted below- (from the link).  The `find directory -mtime +180` function returns directories as well. So how do I list only files which are not modified in last 6 months and not directories?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Panki .yes. It lists all modified files. But I needed is non-modified list

Comment: As for your "modification" of the question: did you try `find directory -type f (etc.)` to ensure only files, and not directories, match?

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/164352/how-can-i-find-files-that-are-not-modified-in-the-last-five-months). I should have searched it little farther . Posting the answer as is.

`find directory -mtime +150`
for the files not modified in this period (`-150` will list the modified files).

Adding comment above for filtering only files

`find directory -mtime +150 -type f`